# How to align TextBlock and TextBox text on one baseline

Tags: layout, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to figure out a nice layout for a group of controls with labels. If i have a label on the left of a textbox for example, the base line of the label and the textbox are not on the same vertical position. An often workaround ist to just vertically center both controls but that doesn't look nice if you have multi line textbox controls.

I got a few combinations.

I hoped a relative panel would provide the option to align the baseline like it does with the android relative layout panel. Unfortunately it doesn't.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
  <RelativePanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Name:" Name="t1"></TextBlock>
    <TextBox Text="Content" RelativePanel.RightOf="t1" ></TextBox>
  </RelativePanel>
</Grid>
```

A grid does not help as well.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Label}" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="Content" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBox>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Obviously a horizontal stackpanel has no magic as well.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Label}" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="Content" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

A vertical stackpanel would avoid the problem, but i'd prefer the label on the left of the control.

```
  <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Label}" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
      <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="Content" ></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

Do you have any ideas how to align baselines which is / or maybe a nice layout idea for a lot of input controls and labels?

Comment: `VerticalAlignment="Center"` for `Textbox` in horizontal `StackPanel` should do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a quick look through the docs and I don't think there is any equivalent to Android's baseline alignment in UWP. Text controls don't expose the position of their baseline for panels to make use of, as it is highly dependent on the template of the control (which can be completely changed, unlike in Android where the visual appearance of views are sort of hard-coded).

Anyway, by inspecting the visual tree of a textbox, I found that the innermost TextBoxView (the control which actually displays and handles text input for the TextBox control) renders text in the same way that a TextBlock does (meaning the padding and such is the same). So as long as we can align the top edges of the TextBlock to the TextBoxView, then the text for both controls will be at the same vertical position. Of course, the font and font size for both controls needs to be the same (which it is by default).

The TextBoxView is pushed down by its parent ScrollContentPresenter by 3px (effective pixels), and the text box border by 2px. So you just need to add 5px of top margin to the TextBlock and the text for both controls will align.

[image: Screenshot]

FYI this is based on the default TextBox template provided by SDK version 14393 which I am using. Microsoft can change these styles with new SDK versions.

---

Looking at the Android docs, the View class has a method [getBaseline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getBaseline()); in UWP, UIElement (or FrameworkElement) has no such equivalent. Searching the visual tree and trying to determine the baseline of the first text element you see mightn't work in every case (some elements have more than one text element).

If you're going to have lots of these left-labelled-elements, some suggestions:

- Create a UserControl with the label and textbox in the correct position. That way you only have the margin hardcoded in one place in your code and if you need to change it you only need to change one piece of code.
- The TextBox control (like many others) has a Header property where you can specify text which will be displayed immediately above the textbox. You can change the template so that the header will be to the left of the textbox instead.

It seems that the recommended way is to use the Header property and have the label on top. Most UWP apps do this (in Groove when you edit song info, Edge's settings pane, etc). This is probably because when displayed on a mobile device, there isn't much horizontal space.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer even with graphics. I understand what you are saying, but i hoped there is another way. Working with margins or paddings is a little annoying, because one has to figure out which margins are right for each control combination you are using. And maybe fonts are not equal in all scenarios. Maybe it could be worth to create a helper functions which inspects the visual tree/template of a control, searches for textblock elements and tries to calculate the baseline. And then with that functionality maybe even create an own layout panel.I'll accept later :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to not create a `TextBlock` and a `TextBox`, but simply two `TextBox` elements with any of the layouts you have suggested at the top. Then apply the following Style to the `TextBox` element which should only show the label to make it look like a `TextBlock`:

```
<Style x:Key="TransparentTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="IsTapEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
</Style>
```

I *think* setting `IsReadOnly`, `IsTapEnabled` and `IsTabStop` should be enough to disable all potential interactions (just made a quick test), but to be sure you could also simply set `IsEnabled` to false and modify the template to look the same like if it would be enabled (you can get the default template in VS2015 by opening the *Document Outline* window (if you don't have it visible, you can find it in *View* > *Other windows*) open the visual tree to get to your item, then right-click, *Edit Template* and *Edit a Copy...*).

Comment: Thanks for your anwer. Instead of this solution i'd prefer the "solution" with margins because it is more adaptable to other controls for example Combobox, Checkbox, etc.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this approach has very negative consequences for accessibility. For example, with a screen reader, whereas using `TextBlock`s would read the text as expected (`string 1, string 2`), a `TextBox` would make the screen read something closer to `string 1, edit, read only, disabled, string 2, edit, read only, disabled,`. You can mitigate this with a custom AutomationPeer, but it becomes harder to get right. I would stick with the margin approach because it does accessibility right by default. This is an interesting approach to a frustrating problem, though!

Comment: Oops! I misread the original question. If you update my examples to expect `string 1, edit` as the readout for the first element, my original comment still stands.